# Java Processing input from a file

Tags: java, oop

So I am doing this past sample final exam where the question asks to read input from a file and then process them into words. **The end of a sentence is marked by any word that ends with one of the three characters . ? !**

I was able to write a code for this however I can only *split them into sentences* using scanner class and using use.Delimiter. I want to process them into words and see if a word ends in the above sentence separator then I will just stop adding words into the sentence class.
Any help would be appreciated as I am learning this on my own and this is what I came up with. My code is here.

```
File file = new File("finalq4.txt");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    scanner.useDelimiter("[.?!]");
    while(scanner.hasNext()){
        sentCount++;
        line = scanner.next();
        line = line.replaceAll("\\r?\\n", " ");
        line = line.trim();
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");
        wordsCount += tokenizer.countTokens();
        sentences.add(new Sentence(line,wordsCount));
        for(int i = 0; i < line.replaceAll(",|\\s+|'|-","").length(); i++){
            currentChar = line.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isDigit(currentChar)) {
            }else{
                lettersCount++;
            }
        }
    }
```

What I am doing in this code is that I am splitting the input into sentences using the Delimiter method and then counting the words, letters of the entire file and storing the sentences in a sentence class.

**If I want to split this into words, how can I do that without using the scanner class.**

*Some of the input from the file that I have to process is here*:

> Text that follows is based on the Wikipedia page on cryptography!
>
> Cryptography is the practice and study of hiding information. In modern times,
> cryptography is considered to be a branch of both mathematics and computer
> science, and is affiliated closely with information theory, computer security, and
> engineering. Cryptography is used in applications present in technologically
> advanced societies; examples include the security of ATM cards, computer
> passwords, and electronic commerce, which all depend on cryptography.....

I can further elaborate on this question if it needs explanation.

What I want to be able to do is to keep adding words to the sentence class and stop if the word ends in one of the above sentence separator. And then read another word and keep adding the words until I hit another separator.

Comment: Scanner is pretty good. .you can too read the file line by line

Comment: What about using `String.split` ?

Comment: Yeah scanner is good and it is easy as well, not  a lot of coding to do. @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ

Comment: Yeah i know about split method but how will i split them? i don't know the regex for that. @ScaryWombat

Comment: You mean that i can split the words using scanner class and then add them to the sentence class? I was only able to split line which ended in , or ! or ?. Can i do that using Scanner class? @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ

Comment: You should do replacement `line = line.replaceAll(",|\\s+|'|-","")` before `for` loop.

Comment: Is this how i can split them, is it possible in java to do something like this? `s.split(".|?|!"` @ScaryWombat

Comment: I know it is bad programming practice but does it make any difference to the values? I just wrote this method in like 1 hour so it is less than a perfect version of my final program. Sorry about that. Also the purpose of that line is not to count any punctuation or comma in the letter count @olsli

Comment: The StringTokenizer does already allow you to process word by word: (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) using tokenizer.hasNextToken and tokenizer.nextToken. Instead of Scanner you could use a Reader to get the lines and then split it into words.

Comment: @Saad It seems like a bug. You use unchanged `line` inside loop.

Comment: @Saad try `line = "--123"` it returns `2`.

Comment: I am not quite sure about what you mean by unchanged `line`? The code is working but i want to split them into words. i don't know how will i go about doing that @olsli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so i have been solving this question through several techniques and one of the approach was above. however i was able to solve this with another approach as well which does not involve using `Scanner` class. This one was much more accurate and it gave me the exact output whereas in the above i was off by a few words and letters.

```
try {
        input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
        strLine = input.readLine();
        while(strLine!= null){

            String[] tokens = strLine.split("\\s+");
            for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
                if(strLine.isEmpty()){
                    continue;
                }
                String s = tokens[i];
                wordsJoin += tokens[i] + " ";

                wordCount += i;
                int len = s.length();
                String charString = s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "");
                for(int k =0; k<charString.length(); k++){
                    currentChar = charString.charAt(k);
                    if(Character.isLetter(currentChar)){ 
                        lettersCount++;
                    }  
                }
                if (s.charAt(len - 1) == '.' || s.charAt(len - 1) == '?' || s.charAt(len - 1) == '!') {
                    sentences.add(new Sentence(wordsJoin, wordCount));
                    sentCount++;
                    numOfWords += countWords(wordsJoin);
                    wordsJoin = "";
                    wordCount = 0;
                } 
            }
            strLine = input.readLine();
        }
```

This might be useful for anyone doing the same problem or just need an idea of how to count letters, words and sentences from a text file.

Answer (score 1):

The snippet below shall work

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file = new File("final.txt");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    scanner.useDelimiter("[.?!]");
    int sentCount;
    List<Sentence> sentences = new ArrayList<Sentence>();
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        String line = scanner.next();
        if (!line.equals("")) { /// for the ... in the end
            int wordsCount = 0;
            String[] wordsOfLine = line.split(" ");
            for (int i = 0; i < wordsOfLine.length; i++) {
                wordsCount++;
            }
            Sentence sentence = new Sentence(line, wordsCount);
            sentences.add(sentence);
        }
    }
}



public class Sentence {
    String line = "";
    int wordsCount = 0;
    public Sentence(String line, int wordsCount) {
        this.line = line;
        this.wordsCount=wordsCount;
}
```

Comment: If i am following your program right then the line gets a sentence so it is basically the same as my program. I want to split it into words and then add every word to the sentence class and stop when it ends in ?.!

Comment: I don't think your program is doing that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a buffered reader to read every line of the file. Then split every line into a sentence with the split method and finally to get the words just split the sentence with the same method. In the end it would look something like this:

```
BufferedReader br;
try{
    br = new BufferedReader(new File(fileName));
}catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
    sb.append(line);
}
String[] sentences = sb.toString().split("\\.");
for(String sentence:sentences){
    String word = sentence.split(" ");
    //Add word to sentence...
}
try{
    br.close();
}catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```